# Some low-rep users cannot post anywhere

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-users

We have got [2 reports](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/697/where-do-new-users-file-bug-reports-etc) in math.SE that [some](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/660) [users](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1384) below 100 reputation cannot post any answers or questions. They keep receiving

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: users with less than 100 reputation can only post questions every X minutes; try again later.

(X = 3 or 20), even if they have waited long enough or not asked any questions before. One user, [Pierre-Yves Gaillard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150323/pierre-yves-gaillard), tried to post a question at here, but also failed with the same message.

Comment: If a user can't post any answers or questions, how can they report that they can't post any answers or questions? :D

Comment: Happened to me too. :(

Comment: @Maxim, it was reported in chat, at least: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/chats/message/111656?offset=-240

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apologies for the inconvenience, this was indeed a bug on our end.

Fix should now be deployed.