# Could not answer or ask questions from Starbucks

Tags: bug, status-completed, time-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Some low-rep users cannot post anywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61817/some-low-rep-users-cannot-post-anywhere)

While I was at Starbucks earlier today, I tried answering a few questions and asking a few questions, but the Stack Overflow system would not let me do it.  I kept getting the "You can't post more than once in three minutes" error, or the "You can't ask more than one question in 20 minutes" error.  When I went home, everything worked fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: The coffee nazis are probably sniggering into their double decaf skinny chai lattes about this one :)

Comment: It was a bug that was fixed earlier today. I had the same thing, nothing to do with Starbucks: http://scorcho.tumblr.com/post/988192497/so-issue

Answer (score 0):

You probably ran into [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61817/some-low-rep-users-cannot-post-anywhere).

Or, less likely, someone from starbucks already posted a question/answer. It's IP based, not account based.

Comment: Ah, public hotspots and large networks. The only issue with IP based systems