# "only post questions every N minutes" error is quite annoying

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Some low-rep users cannot post anywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61817/some-low-rep-users-cannot-post-anywhere)

I couldn't answer my own question due to the following error, even after captcha passed.

```
Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

users with less than 100 reputation can only post questions every 3 minutes; try again later.
```

Of note, I had a hard time wasting like 10 minutes to post a feedback here, similarly witnessing "oops" message so many times, which I think is not a good user experience.

I'm assuming it is a bug, no?

Comment: It was. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61817/some-low-rep-users-cannot-post-anywhere

Answer (score 1):

> *"I couldn't answer my own question [because I was blocked from posting another question]"*?

Huh?

To answer you own question either post an *answer* or edit the existing question body. Post come in different types on SOFUE{*}, and it is important to use the right one for each task.

---

{*}

- Stack Overflow
- Server Fault
- Super User
- Stack Exchange

that is to say "these sites".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is intentional to prevent manual user spamming. You care read about the reasoning behind rate-limiting on [Jeff's blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/rate-limiting-and-velocity-checking.html).

Comment: It happened to me as well. Even i tried nearly 5 to 10 minutes later. Then too, I had the problem. But, mean while I submitted comments and upvoted an answer those things worked for me very nice. Will those things increases the 3 minutes due time as well? Much worried. Thanks in advance.